# Formik - Stop field from being validated if it hasn't changed

Tags: formik

When Formik runs validation, all my fields are validated.
One of my operations is really expensive (DB lookup).
I'd like to not run this validation if it hasn't changed. How can I achieve this?

I'm using withFormik Higher order component.

One option I considered was to track the current value and the last validated value. If different, then run the validation. Maybe that could be `const [lastValidated, setLastValidated] = useState();` in the underlying component. But I'm not sure how to access state on my underlying comopnent.

```
const Guest = (props) => {
  // maybe lastValidated here?
};

const formikEnhancer = withFormik({
  validate: (values, props) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const errors = {};

      // Runs validation on all fields

      }
 });

export default formikEnhancer(Guest);
```

Comment: Having the same problem, did you find any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [field-level validation](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation#field-level-validation) in this case. It could give you more flexibility in checking for changes in this specific input so you can bail before the expensive operation is run.

Comment: I've tried this but the field level validation runs when I'm editing other fields... I'm having the same proble as OP